# VueJS Global Mixin readonly variable not accessible from method in a component

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-mixin

I was trying to use vuejs as a frontend scaffolding with WP restapi. I needed the api url generated by wordpress accessible to all the vue components. Here is what I did:

```
Vue.mixin({
  data: function () {
    return {
      get apiURL () {
        return document.querySelector('link[rel="https://api.w.org/"]').href;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The problem is that, I can access the variable is accessible from inside the template tag, like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <p>{{ apiURL }}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

But I can't access it inside a method from the component:

```
methods: {
  loadPosts: function () {
    this.status = 'Loading...';
    axios.get( apiURL + 'wp/v2/posts').then((response) => {
      this.status = '';
      this.posts = response.data;
      console.log(response.data);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

In this part of the code, it gives me this error:

`ReferenceError: apiURL is not defined`

What is the right way to do it. I am using VueJS version 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:** Use `this.apiURL`:

```js
methods: {
  loadPosts: function () {
    axios.get( this.apiURL + 'wp/v2/posts').then((response) => {
      ...
    });
  }
}
```

```js
Vue.mixin({
  data: function () {
    return {
      get apiURL () {
        return 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/';
      }
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    loadPosts: function () {
      console.log(`loadPosts: ${this.apiURL}`);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="loadPosts">loadPosts()</button>
</div>
```

---

The global mixin adds a data field (`apiURL`) to all Vue instances, and you would access that field as any other [data field](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods) declared locally in the component (i.e., using `this.FIELDNAME`, so `this.apiURL` in your case). Otherwise without the `this` keyword, accessing `apiURL` refers to some global variable (of `window`), which isn't necessarily defined.